# Define function in the class body not in constructor

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code. Is there a way to define the log, warn and error functions like "normal" class functions?

```js
class ConsoleLogger {
    constructor (enable, methods) {

        this.log =function() {
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console, "MY PREFIX");
        }();

        this.warn =function() {
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.warn, console, "MY PREFIX");
        }();

        this.error =function() {
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.error, console, "MY PREFIX");
        }();


    }
}

// ...

logger = new ConsoleLogger();
logger.log("Log Message");
```

Is there a way to do this, but to have the same functionality as the upper code?

```js
class ConsoleLogger {
   log() {
       //do something 
   }
}
```

Comment: How about `this.log = console.log` or `Object.assign(this, console)` in the constructor?

Comment: I will extend the answer, as I want to add a bit of logic and not use directly console.log

Comment: Try out this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon-logger
If you not you can also look at the source code on github and implement one of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try the following code.

```
class ConsoleLogger {
    constructor (enable, methods) {

    }

    log() {
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console, "MY PREFIX");
        }

    warn() {
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.warn, console, "MY PREFIX");
        }

    error() {
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.error, console, "MY PREFIX");
        }
}
```

And call the function as

```
new ConsoleLogger().log()("test log")
```

Will return

```
MY PREFIX test log
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `log` to the class. Use `console.log()` inside it and spread the arguments passed with your prefix argument to `console.log`

```js
class ConsoleLogger {
  log(...args) {
    console.log("MY PREFIX", ...args)
  }
}

new ConsoleLogger().log("message 1", "message 2");
```